# AWS Lambda - callback("some error type") equivalent in Java 8

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How do I make a lambda function report a failure in Java 8?

I see this is possible in Node.js. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html

> **Using the Callback Parameter**
>   The Node.js runtime v4.3 supports the optional callback parameter. You
>   can use it to explicitly return information back to the caller. The
>   general syntax is:
>
> `callback(Error error, Object result);`
>
> Where:
>
> - error – is an optional parameter that you can use to provide results
>     of the failed Lambda function execution. When a Lambda function >succeeds, you can pass null as the first parameter.
> - result – is an optional parameter that you can use to provide the result of a successful function execution. The result provided must be
>     JSON.stringify compatible. If an error is provided, this parameter is
>     ignored.
>
> **Note**
>
> Using the callback parameter is optional. If you don't use the
>   optional callback parameter, the behavior is same as if you called the
>   callback() without any parameters. You can specify the callback in
>   your code to return information to the caller.
>
> If you don't use callback in your code, AWS Lambda will call it
>   implicitly and the return value is null.
>
> When the callback is called (explicitly or implicitly), AWS Lambda
>   continues the Lambda function invocation until the Node.js event loop
>   is empty.
>
> The following are example callbacks:
>
> `callback();     // Indicates success but no information returned to`
>      `the caller. callback(null); // Indicates success but no information`
>      `returned to the caller. callback(null, "success");  // Indicates`
>      `success with information returned to the caller. callback(error);`
>      `//  Indicates error with error information returned to the caller.`
>
> AWS Lambda treats any non-null value for the error parameter as a
>   handled exception.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45108530/is-there-any-way-to-signal-an-error-in-aws-lambda-for-java-without-throwing-an-e

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just throw an exception and do not catch it anywhere. Any uncatched exception causes Lambda failure. You can see more information about how to report failures in AWS Lambda with Java: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-exceptions.html

```
public TestResponse handleRequest(TestRequest request, Context context) throws RuntimeException {
   throw new RuntimeException("Error");
}
```

Note the `throws` declaration which allows to throw an unhandled exception to out of the method.

Comment: That's my problem. If I try to throw an exception in the handleRequest method. I'm getting a compile error: "Unhandled exception type Exception". I don't want to handle the exception though. Eclipse is forcing me to wrap it in a Try/Catch

Comment: Java basics :) Mark your handler method with throws statement, then compiler won't cry

"public TestResponse handleRequest(TestRequest request, Context context) throws RuntimeException"

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much!!

Comment: RuntimeException and subclasses are not required to be declared to be thrown.  These are so-called unchecked exceptions.